# Prove the function is concave, using log-sum-exp and geometric mean.

Tags: convex-analysis

Suppose $p<1,p\ne0$. Show that the function
$$ f(x) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} $$
with **dom**$\ f=\Bbb{R}_{++}^n$ is concave, where **dom** represents domain and $\Bbb{R}_{++}=\{x\in\Bbb{R}:x>0\}$. *Hint*. Adapt the proofs for the log-sum-exp function and the geometric mean.

- *Log-sum-exp*.$\quad$The function $f(x)=\log(e^{x_1}+\cdots+e^{x_n})$ is convex on $\Bbb{R}^n$.
- *Geometric mean*.$\quad$The geometric mean $f(x)=(\Pi_{i=1}^{n} x_i )^{1/n}$ is concave on **dom**$\ f=\Bbb{R}_{++}^n$.

---

I can prove whether $f(x)$ is concave or not using 2nd derivative of the function. However, I have failed to prove it using the above two things; *log-sum-exp* and *geometric mean*. Please let me know how to solve it? Thank you for reading my question.